# Performing CRUD operations from android to server?

Tags: android, database, authentication, crud

Could you guys link me to any resources or point me in the right direction? I've been searching on google all day, but I only get SQLite tutorials and articles, maybe I'm not looking in the right direction.

Basically I want to write data into a mysql database from my android applications. I want to save things like subscriptions and preferences for each user, for a specific user (so I'll also have to implement some sort of login system)

Can I do this directly from my android application, or will I have to use PHP to handle the requests on the server and then send the data in JSON or xml or something like that?

Any information on both the CRUD and the login system is very much welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do that from android app , you can use php like you said or set up a socket application with java depending on your needs and possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

The second you said. :)

You need to get a restful framework or stuff like that.
( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3466179/best-lightweight-restful-framework-for-php-5-3 )